# Get branch on Origin not on local

Tags: git, github

I ran in to a situation where I was working on two separate machines and ended up with the following:

Laptop A:

- main
- branch_a
- branch_b

Laptop B:

- main
- branch_c

Origin:

- main
- branch_a
- branch_b
- branch_c

I am now done working on Laptop B and will continue working on Laptop A. How do I go about getting just branch_c locally on to my Laptop A and then working from there only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand the question, but if you simply want to access branch_c on laptop A, here are the instructions.

First you must fetch, to get the latest on the remote server. Then checkout branch_c.

run the following:

```
git fetch
git checkout branch_c
```

that is it

Comment: `git branch --track branch_c origin/branch_c` can be a better choice

Comment: That's how I understood the question too but if that's the case OP should read some basic Git tutorial

Comment: @Ôrel: why is it better?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk that is exactly my question. I want to create a branch on my Laptop A that tracks branch_c. 

I tried reading some git stuff online before posting as it wasnt clear to me.

Comment: I mean it is more explicit, `git checkout` can manipulate a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this "properly" (for whatever definition you want to use for "properly") requires understanding Git's names.  *Branch* names are just a specific subset of Git's names, which also include *tag* names, *remote-tracking* names, *replacement* names, internal names for bisection, and many others.

These names exist—or mostly exist, depending on whose definition you use—as one or another form of *reference* or *ref*.  A ref is, or mostly is, a name that starts with `refs/` and goes on to include another component, such as `stash` or `heads/` or `tags/` and so on.  Each slash separates a component, much as with a Unix/Linux style path name: the only thing that's special here is that all of these refs start with `refs/`.

The exception, if you choose to define it this way—some parts of Git do and some don't—is that there are some special refs like `HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, and so on, that don't start with `refs/`.  Some Git documentation considers these ordinary refs, and some doesn't, but the important thing is that they do exist yet don't start with `refs/`.  *Only the ones that do start with `refs/`, plus the special name `HEAD`,* are allowed to "escape" from your Git repository to be seen by some other Git repository.

In other words, every Git repository has *its own set of refs*.  But, when you connect one Git repository to another Git repository—which you do with `git fetch` or `git push`—you may allow *your* names to be seen by the other Git repository, and the other Git repository may allow *its* names to be seen by *your* Git repository.

Meanwhile, *each name stores one hash ID*.  That's what they're good for: storing one hash ID.  Git *needs* the hash IDs to find commits.  *Git does not need the names!*  It only needs the hash IDs.  If you can supply the hash ID, without the name, that's sufficient.

#### You should thus hold the following picture in your head

Each Git repository has:

- commits, which have hash IDs;
- some names—i.e., refs—that let *you*, a human, tell Git a hash ID without *you* having to memorize the hash IDs yourself.

When you use `git push` or `git fetch`, or `git pull` which starts by running `git fetch`, you are telling your Git to connect to another Git repository.  That *other* Git repository *also* has commits (which have hash IDs) and names.  Your Git may look at their names and get commits from them—that's the `git fetch` operation—or may send commits to them and ask them to set some of their names: that's the `git push` operation.

Those names that start with `refs/heads/` are *branch names*, and these are the names you use most often.  Git allows you (the human) to leave off the `refs/heads/` part, and will stick that part on automatically as needed to find the commit locally.  You can explicitly write out `refs/heads/` to *force* Git to use something as a *branch* name, if needed, but usually we just let Git do its thing and are lazy and type in `main` and not `refs/heads/main`.

#### Fetch and push are different

When you use `git push`, you will run it like this at least once:

```
git push -u origin somebranch
```

The `origin` here is the name you are using to store a URL, by which your Git can call up some other Git repository over the Internet.  The `somebranch` part is short for `refs/heads/somebranch`: we let Git fill in the `refs/heads/` for us.

Your Git uses this to find your latest commit for your `somebranch` branch.  Your Git then makes sure *their* Git repository has this commit and all the commits needed to lead up to that commit too, and then—once your Git is sure they have them, first *sending over* those commits and anything else needed—your Git will ask their Git to create or update *their* `refs/heads/somebranch` name.  That way, your Git and their Git will both have branches named `somebranch`, and both branch names will refer to the *same commit*.

It's the *commits* that matter to Git—not the branch names, just the commits!  The *branch names* only matter to humans.  But we want Git to serve us, not the other way around, so we want the branch names to match too.

Once you've done one `git push -u` like this, you can just run:

```
git push
```

Your Git will figure out that your current branch is `somebranch`, and use its *upstream* setting—that's what the `-u` is for with `git push -u origin somebranch`, to *set* the upstream setting—to do `git push origin somebranch` for you.  Sometimes, *creating* a branch name *in* your repository *automatically sets its upstream* and then you can use `git push` without the `-u`.  Sometimes it doesn't, and you need the `git push -u`, or `git branch --set-upstream-to`, or some other method to set the branch's upstream.

But `git fetch` is different!  When you run `git fetch` you should usually just run it by itself, or with the name of the remote `origin`:

```
git fetch origin
```

This has your Git call up the other Git repository, using the URL stored under the name `origin` as before.  But this time your Git is *getting* stuff *from* them.  Your Git asks them to list out *all* their branch names.  They do that, and then your Git takes each of their *names* and *changes* them.  Your Git turns their `main`—which is, strictly speaking, `refs/heads/main`—and turns that into your `origin/main`, which is short for `refs/remotes/origin/main`.  Your Git turns their `branch_a`, if they have one, into `origin/branch_a`.  This repeats for every branch name they have: every one of their `refs/heads/*` names becomes a `refs/remotes/origin/*` name.

Having made these changes, your Git also gets from them any commits they have, that you don't, that you'll need to create-or-update *all* your `refs/remotes/origin/*` names.  And, once you have all these commits and supporting objects, your Git will then create or update all these names.

These `refs/remotes/origin/*` names—which your Git lets you abbreviate as `origin/main` and so on—are your *remote-tracking names* for the remote named `origin`.  Because they include the word `origin` in their name, they're separate from any other remote-tracking names.

#### Adding more remotes

This separation means you can add more *remotes*.  Running:

```
git remote add computer1 <url>
```

allows you to run:

```
git fetch computer1
```

(assuming there's some URL by which your current computer—computer0?—can reach computer1).  That will let your Git get, from "their" (your-on-computer1) Git repository, all of their commits and all of their branch names.  Your Git will now create-or-update `refs/remotes/computer1/*` in your repository.

#### What if you can't log in from one of your computers to another?

What if you can't actually log in to your laptop-A to your laptop-B?  For instance, if they're both running Windows, they probably have no server-like capabilities.<sup>1</sup>  In this case, you'll need to use `git push` from the laptop that *has* the branch name, to send the branch to some hosting server that both laptops can reach.  This will also send any commits needed.

Then, once the commits and branch name exist where you *can* get them, you run `git fetch` to there.  That gets the commits *and* creates a *remote-tracking name*, such as `origin/branch_c` or `laptopB/branch_c`, locally.  Now you have a *remote-tracking name* on laptop A that finds the right commit, which you also have on laptop A.  So now you can create a *branch* name on laptop A:

```
git branch branch_c origin/branch_c
```

for instance.

If you *were* able to start sshd directly on laptopB and created a `laptopB` remote and ran `git fetch laptopB` to get `laptopB/branch_c` on laptop A, you can run:

```
git branch branch_a laptopB/branch_c
```

for instance.

Note that these `git branch` commands *create* `branch_c` locally, here on laptop A, with an upstream set.  The upstream that is set is `origin/branch_c` or `laptopB/branch_c`, whatever your second argument was.  If you want to *change* the upstream, just remember to run `git push -u` later as needed.  The `-u` option tells `git push`: *If this push works, please run `git branch --set-upstream-to` for me*, with the arguments to the `git branch --set-upstream-to` command setting the upstream of the current branch to whatever branch you just created-or-updated on whichever remote you just pushed-to.

---

<sup>1</sup>If they're both running Linux, or even just one of them is, you can start up an `sshd` on the Linux laptops and use ssh access, which will usually be the way to do what you want.